# If $f:\mathbb{R}^m\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$ and $g(t)=f(a+tv)$, how do we determine that $g'(t)$ is a continuous function?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, continuity

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^m\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$ and let $t\rightarrow a+tv$  be a parameterized curve such that $g(t)=f(a+tv)$ where $a,v\in\mathbb{R}^m$. Then the derivative is $g'(t)=f'(a+tv)v$ from the chain rule.

How do we determine that $g'(t)$ is a continuous function? In my book without any explanation it claims that $g'$ is continuous if the partial derivatives of $f$ exists and they are continuous.

I tried thinking about it in the case where $f(x,y)=z$. If the partial derivative with respect to $x$ exists and is continuous and if $g_{y_0}(x)=f(x,y_0)$ for some $y_0\in\mathbb{R}$ then $g_{y_0}'(x)$ is continuous. Geometrically this means that the intersection of graph of $f$ and the vertical plane $y_0=y$ is a curve and has a continuous derivative. Similar thing can be done if we take the partial derivative with respect to $y$.
But there could be other curves on graph of $f$ that do not go along the x-axis or y-axis. How do we determine if they have a continuous derivative?

Comment: $x \to f'(x)$ is a matrix valued continuous function  and this implies that $g'$ is continuous.

Comment: So if the partial derivatives exist then the matrix valued function is continuous so $g′$
 is continuous? Is $f'(x)$ the jacobian matrix? What is the definition for a matrix valued function to be continuous?

Comment: Partial derivatives have to be continuous also. Just existence is not enough. There is a matrix norm and  a mtrix distance on the set of all $m \times n$ matrices and continuity is w.r.t. this matrix. But you can also think of this as continuity if the $(i,j)$ element of $f'(x)$ for each pair $(i,j)$.